# $(1 2)(3 4)$ does not commute with any nonidentity element of odd order in $A_5$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

On Dummit's Abstract Algebra on p. 128, it says:

> "It is easy to see that $(1 2)(3 4)$ ... does not commute with any non-identity element of odd order in $A_5$."

But I don't find it easy.

Any help, please?

Comment: An element of odd order is either a 3-cycle or the 5-cycle, you can try all the possibilities.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a bit of reasoning that generalizes a little better than just brute force.

This is equivalent to showing that $\tau(12)(34) \tau^{-1}\neq(12)(34)$ for the $\tau$ you specified. Fortunately this is easy to compute using the trick that $\tau(12)(34) \tau^{-1}=(\tau(1)\tau(2))(\tau(3)\tau(4))$. (My order of composition is to execute the rightmost permutation first.)

So if we tried to find a nonidentity permutation $\tau$ such that $\tau(12)(34) \tau^{-1}=(12)(34)$, it would have to move at least one of $\{1,2,3,4\}$, and $5$ is fixed. There are then these cases:

1. The symbols $1,2$ are transposed, the symbols $3,4$ are transposed, or maybe both pairs are transposed.
2. The symbols $1,3$ are transposed (and accordingly $2,4$ are transposed), or else $1,4$ are tranposed (and accordingly $2,3$ are transposed.)

A single transposition is of even order, so the only candidates are products of two transpositions, which are all three cycles. But that means that exactly one of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ is fixed by $\tau$. How could this be? If you fix any symbol in $(12)(34)$ and want to preserve the equality above, then you automatically fix its partner. By this contradiction, we see no $\tau$ exists.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $\tau=(12)(34)$ commutes with $\sigma$. You have two situations:

**Case 1:** $\sigma(5)= a  \neq 5$.

Then $\sigma(\tau(5))=\sigma(5)=a$ while  $\tau \sigma(5) = \tau(a)$. As $a \in \{1,2,3,4\}$ it follows that $\tau(a) \neq a$ which proves that

$$ \sigma(\tau(5)) \neq \tau (\sigma(5))$$

**Case 2:** $\sigma(5)= 5$. Then, sigma must have another fixed point $a \in \{ 1,2,3,4 \}$, which is unique. Then, as $\tau(a) \neq a$ we have

$\sigma(\tau(a))\neq \tau (a)$ while  $\tau( \sigma(a)) = \tau(a)$.

Answer (score 1):

The book has demonstrated that the representatives of the cycle types of $A_{5}$ are given by:

\begin{equation}
1, \quad \left(1\ 2\ 3\right), \quad \left(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\right), \quad \text{and} \quad \left(1\ 2\right)\left(3\ 4\right).
\end{equation}

It is also established that:
\begin{equation}
C_{A_{5}}\left(\left(1\ 2\ 3\right)\right) = \left\langle (1\ 2\ 3 )\right\rangle, \quad
C_{A_{5}}\left(\left(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\right)\right) = \left\langle (1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5) \right\rangle,
\end{equation} and the centralizers of other odd-order, non-identity elements are similarly obtained.

From this, we see that any non-identity element of odd order in $A_{5}$ commutes exclusively with elements of its cyclic subgroup. The element $\left(1\ 2\right)\left(3\ 4\right)$ is not in any of these cyclic subgroups, which means it doesn't commute with any non-identity element of odd order in $A_{5}$.