# Why doesn't (12)(34) commute with any odd ordered element in $A_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In Dummit and foote, for the proof for the simplicity of $A_5$, it claims that it is "easy" to see that $(12)(34)$ doesn't commute with any odd elements in $A_5$ and it commutes with $(13)(24)$, I have absolutely not idea why this is considered "easy", what method did the author use to quickly see this?

It further claimed that "it follows that $|C_{A_5}((12)(34)| = 4$, which again, I don't see how it follows from the above statement without also checking other two cycles do not commute with $(12)(34)$.

Comment: Your question is already has an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504866/1-23-4-does-not-commute-with-any-nonidentity-element-of-odd-order-in-a-5?rq=1)

Comment: @ChinnapparajR: Why didn't you vote to close as duplicate?

Comment: Thank you all. I feel somewhat shameful reading the answer.

Comment: @joriki: I don't know ho to do!

Comment: @ChinnapparajR: Sorry, I wasn't aware that this requires $3000$ reputation, I just read up on this here: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions.

Comment: Ok! no problem!