# Simplicity of the $A_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, simple-groups

In the proof given in Abstract Algebra by Dummit and Foote, page 128, it states that $(1~2)(3~4)$ commutes with $(1~3)(2~4)$ but does not commute with any element of odd order in $A_5$. So it follows that the centralizer of $A_5$ is a group of order $4$.
I understand the first sentence, but I don't understand why the centralizer cannot be of order $12$ without explicitly checking the conjugations.

Comment: If the centralizer had order 12, there would be an element of odd order (namely, 3) commuting with (13)(24).

Comment: you may check this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/504866/1093844